# How can i not set <pk> at my url to get certain data?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My api was set to `api/barrel/details/<int:pk>` originally but i want to make the delete function into `api/barrel` (which only have `get` and `post` function) without parsing the `pk`

```
class BarrelAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self,request):
        barrel = Barrel.objects.all() #queryset
        serializer = BarrelSerializer(barrel, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self,request):
        serializer = BarrelSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
             serializer.save()
             return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED) 

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    
    def delete(self,request):
        try:
            data = request.data
            Barrel.objects.filter(code=data['code']).delete()
            
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

        except Exception as error:
            return Response( status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

It can be done on postman by parsing the 'code'. but when i try on restframework default api browser the delete button showed up but nothing happens after that

Comment: Note, I think it should be <int:pk>

Comment: I'm confused, if you want a list of barrels you don't need a pk at all, if you want one particular barrel you need to somehow tell the server which one you want. I'm not sure what you're asking, something about pk but in the code snippet there's no mention of a primary key at all

Comment: yes i know like u usually set api/details/<int:pk> in the url.py files . what i am asking is is it possible to not set the <int:pk> behind the url or how can i make all CRUD operation in one url with restframework

Answer (score 0):

You should check out:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#mixins
in the long run it will make your life easier..
The url could have any structure you like.
I would also suggest to refer to:
Two scoops of Django that introduce you to various tips, tricks, patterns, code snippets, and techniques